# AppCompat and EditText different underline on different API

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appcompat

I'm trying to make underline line color change for `EditText` (it will be used for input's validation, so it must be able to change in runtime).

I'm using AppCompat library. The problem is that on API 21 and above, I see transparent black line (gray overlay), instead of bolded version.

How to make it the same as in API 16?

I used this code to change tint:

```
    final Drawable originalDrawable = view.getBackground();
    final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(originalDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, Color.RED);
    setBackground(view,wrappedDrawable);
```

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution found by adding these lines to my theme:

```
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText</item>
    <item name="editTextBackground">@drawable/abc_edit_text_material</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not change the background. It's better if you create a theme, and use theme colors (colorPrimary, colorAccent are the most important for widgets) to get the desired effect. Assign the theme to your EditText and enjoy. Note: you should use one of the AppCompat theme as base theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

and in your colors.xml

```
<color name="primary">#ff0000</color>
<color name="accent">#00ff00</color>
```

Comment: You can change the theme at runtime.

Comment: Can you please clarify better your needs? Do you create your widget in java code? Do you inflate your layout?

Comment: I need to change layout (make bottom line red) when EditText field is validated and should display error.

Comment: To show errors, use the setError() method of EditText. If the 'red line' feature is a must have, then I suggest you to implement a custom view to handle this. It's better if you don't try to change Android standard widget behaviour, you never know what can happen on different devices, different android versions, new app compat releases and so on.

Comment: Please read Material Design - [link](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-single-line-text-field)

Comment: Please read TextInputLayout widget. It's been added in the design support library, or take a look at this [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/becoming-material-with-android-design-support-library/)

Comment: Already tried it. Effect is the same as wrapping drawable, but also it forces me to use floating hint, which I don't want.