# Change TintList for StateListDrawable inside RippleDrawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, rippledrawable, statelistdrawable

#### Scope

RippleDrawable has `selector` as `item` inside. It works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/pink_highlight">        
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/pink_highlight" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_selectable_item" />
</ripple>
```

+

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/pink_highlight_focus" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/pink_highlight_press" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/pink_highlight_press" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/pink_highlight_press" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

#### Problem

Can't change selector's default state color with `DrawableCompat.setTintList`

```
RippleDrawable bg = (RippleDrawable) 
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bg_navigation_item, null);
StateListDrawable bgWrap = (StateListDrawable) DrawableCompat.wrap(bg.getDrawable(1));
DrawableCompat.setTintList(bgWrap, new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{Color.WHITE}));
//
someView.setBackground(bg);
```

It doesn't change default selector's state, everything else is ok.

#### Solution

Problem occurred because of 
- misunderstanding of how tinting should work;
- `ColorStateList` better to be loaded fully;

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/pink_highlight">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:tint="@color/selectable_transparent_item" />
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/pink_highlight" />
</ripple>
```

+

```
LayerDrawable bg = (LayerDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bg_selectable_item, null);
Drawable bgWrap = DrawableCompat.wrap(bg.getDrawable(0));
DrawableCompat.setTintList(bgWrap, context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selectable_white_item));
someView.setBackground(bg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `someView.setBackground(bgWrap)` ? You set tint to `bgWrap`, but you need also so set it as background, not your old background.

EDIT: Are you sure that `setTintList` is bugged? Following code works for me on all API >= 15 with AppCompat:

```
public static void tintWidget(View view, ColorStateList colorStateList) {
    final Drawable originalDrawable = view.getBackground();
    final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(originalDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, colorStateList);
    view.setBackground(wrappedDrawable);
}
```

Comment: Yeap, tried to set bgWrap. Anyway, makes no sense, as `wrap` doesn't create new instance.

Comment: "wrapped Drawable and original Drawable – are the same objects." was only true for api>=21, sorry for that. So basically yes, one have to use wrapper drawable. Anyway, if I set a tint for `<selector>` inflater drawable, it doesn't work on any api :(

Comment: Which API do you use? Maybe you have similar problem as me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118289/appcompat-and-edittext-underline-on-different-api

Comment: Also, I found tinting would have no effect on transparent drawable, like

`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>`

Answer (score 1):

Issue 172067:   DrawableCompat#setTintList does not work on Lollipop and above

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172067