# AutoCompleteTextView drop down has different full screen and background color behavior in Android 4+ and Android 5+

Tags: android

Currently, I'm using AutoCompleteTextView, as `Toolbar`'s component.

I want to achieve the following thing.

1. Have `AutoCompleteTextView`'s dropdown almost full screen, with left-right margins.
2. Have `AutoCompleteTextView`'s dropdown background as red.

I use the following code to achieve such behavior

```
// Full screen, but with left-right margins.
mSearchSrcTextView.setDropDownWidth(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
    
int color = Color.parseColor("#ffff0000");

Drawable drawable = mSearchSrcTextView.getDropDownBackground();
drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

// If we use this ColorDrawable, in Android 4.3, the drop down left-right margins will gone.
//ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(color);

mSearchSrcTextView.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

### In Android 4+, it yields desired behavior (With left-right margins, pure red background)

[image]

### In Android 5+, it yields undesired behavior (No margins, not pure red background)

[image]

I was wondering, why there's such different behavior? How can I have some look n feel (Almost full screen with left-right margins, pure red background) in Android 5+, as in Android 4+?

The full workable code to demonstrate the problem can be found here : https://github.com/yccheok/toolbar-experiment/tree/33b7bda84e7ca1b60f4d6d19b863d5f666adfb3d

After you run the project, type "Fr" in `AutoCompleteTextView` in different Android, to see different drop down behavior.

Comment: Found solution for you. Check answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your project.

Add this to your custom `AutoCompleteTextView` in your xmls:

```
    style="@style/MyAutoCompleteTextView"
```

And this to `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyAutoCompleteTextView" parent="android:Widget.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">?attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/editTextBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/editTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
</style>
```

---

Why there is a difference?

For APIs under Lolipop you got default `AutoCompleteTextView` inherited from different values than Lolipop.

Comment: Interesting! I know I can study `sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values\styles.xml` to learn about `android:Widget.AutoCompleteTextView`. But, how do you manage to figure out what is the item name to be used, and what is the item value should be?

Comment: I had similar problem in my project with EditText's bottom line - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118289/appcompat-and-edittext-underline-on-different-api

Comment: I decided to check widget class and then styles, which are used. I saw that `Base.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView` inheirts from three different styles, depending on API used. CTRL+Left Click on this name to get values. I decided to check these which are for API under 21 and it works.